# Jest: how to restore to a previous mocked implementation (not the original)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a set of 3 tests, the first one has the base mocked implementation:

```
Team.query = jest.fn(() => ({
  findOne: () => {
    return {
      is_disabled: false,
    };
  },
}));
```

In the second test, I perform a `Team.query.mockImplementationOnce` with the above, but I change `is_disabled` to `true`.

In the third test, I want to restore it back to the `jest.fn` implementation above. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You're good, no extra work required.

Since `Team.query` is the mock function, it will automatically revert to the previously mocked implementation after one call when it has been overridden with `mockImplementationOnce`:

```js
const Team = { };

Team.query = jest.fn(() => ({
  findOne: () => {
    return {
      is_disabled: false,
    };
  },
}));

test('Team.query', () => {
  expect(Team.query().findOne().is_disabled).toBe(false);  // Success!

  Team.query.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ findOne: () => ({ is_disabled: true }) }));
  expect(Team.query().findOne().is_disabled).toBe(true);  // Success!

  expect(Team.query().findOne().is_disabled).toBe(false);  // Success!

  Team.query.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ findOne: () => ({ is_disabled: 'some text' }) }));
  expect(Team.query().findOne().is_disabled).toBe('some text');  // Success!

  expect(Team.query().findOne().is_disabled).toBe(false);  // Success!
});
```